# no output in julia using ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I have the ijulia enviroment set but I cannot execute julia statements on it.
I get no output from the notebook. Instead, on terminal I have something like this:

```
2014-02-26 12:37:09.315 [NotebookApp] CRITICAL | Malformed message: ['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/adrian/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.3.0.1715.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 68, in _on_zmq_reply
```

It appears is a problem with the zmq library but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with iJulia and Canopy. I do not know what the issue is, but it is often suggested to use Anaconda instead.

Comment: do you know if having both anaconda and canopy interfere with each other? I mean, do I need to uninstall one of them or can I have both?